# Docker SBT Build Stuck on M2 Chip for deployment to GKE

Tags: docker, scala, playframework, sbt

I just switched over to the new Macbook Pro M2 and I'm attempting to build a docker image for a Scala Play app using openjdk8 and sbt 1.3.8. I run

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t image-name
```

This is what my dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM openjdk:8

# Env variables
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.13.0
ENV SBT_VERSION   1.3.8
ENV APP_NAME      somebackend-api
ENV APP_VERSION   1.0-SNAPSHOT

# Install Scala
## Piping curl directly in tar
RUN \
  curl -fsL https://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz | tar xfz - -C /root/ && \
  echo >> /root/.bashrc && \
  echo "export PATH=~/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/bin:$PATH" >> /root/.bashrc

# Install sbt
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /root
ENV PROJECT_HOME /usr/src

COPY ["build.sbt", "/tmp/build/"]
COPY ["project/plugins.sbt", "project/build.properties", "/tmp/build/project/"]
RUN cd /tmp/build && \
 sbt update && \
 sbt compile

RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_HOME/app
WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/app
COPY . $PROJECT_HOME/app

RUN sbt dist
EXPOSE 9000
RUN unzip target/universal/$APP_NAME-$APP_VERSION.zip
RUN chmod +x $APP_NAME-$APP_VERSION/bin/$APP_NAME

ENTRYPOINT $APP_NAME-$APP_VERSION/bin/$APP_NAME
```

Typically the build just hangs indefinitely on sbt compile.

I should note that I have to build this for linux/amd64 since it's being deployed onto an x86_64 machine on GKE

Does anyone know the right way to go about this? Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: is there any error message once it hangs indefinitely? could you show a bit of the message logged during the build?

Comment: Not related to your issue but 3 comments: 1/ you don't need to install Scala (SBT is enough) 2/ you should use a **multi-stage** build to only include the result of `sbt dist` in your final image. 3/ Why run `sbt compile` before copying the sources and in a separate directory?

Comment: @GaëlJ This is a very good point. I will make those changes 

It's been a long time since I changed this file (years). I haven't experienced any issues until I switched to the new Macbook. I can try to just do sbt dist to lighten the load.

Comment: @GastónSchabas It hangs at various points. sometimes sbt compile, sometimes sbt sbtVersion (I can take this out, it's just a check). It's typically on the points that I'm assuming require more computational power - having said that I've alotted quite a bit of resources to Docker.

Comment: sounds like you are building the image from scratch installing sbt and else. That will make your pipeline slower. Have you considered to use [sbt/docker-sbt](https://github.com/sbt/docker-sbt) or [hseeberger/scala-sbt](https://hub.docker.com/r/hseeberger/scala-sbt)? They let you build the image with the sbt and scala version you need. Another option could be use [sbt-native-packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) that lets you build and publish the image from sbt

Comment: Are you able to share your .sbt and .properties files

Answer (score 2):

**SBT** `1.3.x` uses **Scala-SBT** internally. This **Scala-SBT** that comes with `1.3.x` uses **Java Native Access(JNA)** libraries which are not compatible with **Arm64/AArch64** based processors.

I recently faced this issue on my Mac with M1 chip.

Better to use newer versions of SBT, you can probably choose SBT versions `> 1.3.x` which uses **Scala-SBT** with **Java Native Access(JNA)** libraries which are compatible with **Arm64/AArch64** processors.

Currently, I'm using SBT `1.8.4` which works fine on my machine.